# Pressed event for children within a tablerow

Tags: java, android

I've got an imageview and textview within a tablerow.  Whenever I press down on the tablerow I want the imageview src to swap to the same image of a different color.  I also want the textview to change textcolor.  I've been able to accomplish this within a listview using selectors.  No luck with tables though.  I can make the tablerow clickable and change the backgroundcolor of it through a selector when the `android:state_pressed` event fires...but the children within that tablerow don't receive it.  I've got the src of the image and the textcolor of the textview both pointing towards @drawable selectors.  None of the following return true when I'm pressing on the table row: `android:state_focused`, `android:state_pressed`, and `android_selected`.  I did a test where I made the textview clickable.  When I did that if I clicked on the textview itself it changed colors.  So my selector seems to be coded correctly.  I don't want the textview to be clickable though.  I just want the events of the row to be inherited by the children.

I appreciate any help I can get...or working examples.

Thanks.